# linear pattern in residual vs fitted

Tags: r, multiple-regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

**My question is about addressing linear relationships between model residuals and the response variable.**

I am using a linear mixed model to model the relationships between two response variables (timing of breeding and body condition) and several continuous, normally distributed explanatory variables (V1, V2 and V3). Some details:

- Responses: Timing of breeding is the date individuals began breeding (integer values with a slight right skew), and body condition appears to be normally distributed.
- Explanatory: I've centred and scaled all my explanatory variables by subtracting the mean and dividing by the SD; these all appear to be normally distributed.
- Random: Since some individuals were observed in 2+ years, I've included a random effect for each individual (ID).

Models:

```
M.condition <- lmer(BC~V1+V2+V3+(1|ID), data=df)
M.date <- lmer(date~V1+V2+V3+(1|ID), data=df)
```

However, when I look at the residuals vs fitted plots, I see a strong positive, linear relationship for both models. E.g., residuals vs fitted for condition:

```
plot(M.condition)
```

[image]

I've plotted the residuals against the response and explanatory variables in each model, and it appears that the residuals are closely correlated to the response variable for both models. E.g., residuals vs model variables for condition:

```
plot(resid(M.condition) ~ df$BC) #BC is the response variable
plot(resid(M.condition) ~ df$V1)
plot(resid(M.condition) ~ df$V2)
plot(resid(M.condition) ~ df$V3)
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

What is the best way to address this issue?

Here is my data:

```
dput(subset(df, select = c(BC, date, V1, V2, V3, ID)))

structure(list(BC = c(-0.260573242977317, 0.14920620028433, 
-0.325144549188245, -0.452290110902543, -0.452290110902543, -0.92175064646303, 
-0.92175064646303, 0.0171704246579441, 0.486630960218429, 0.956091495778916, 
0.0171704246579441, -0.92175064646303, -0.514884848977274, -1.50618110909955, 
-1.50618110909955, 1.28183962249436, -0.576840865234916, 0.817169500562038, 
0.817169500562038, -0.1121707433026, 0.817169500562038, -1.04151098716723, 
-0.1121707433026, 1.28183962249436, 0.286454894294163, 2.06098346331016, 
-2.07880489572322, 0.221077525961993, 0.221077525961993, 2.06098346331016, 
-0.69887544271209, 0.221077525961993, -0.23889895837505, 1.60100697897312, 
1.14103049463608, -0.69887544271209, 1.14103049463608, 1.14103049463608, 
-0.23889895837505, -2.13196800697825, -0.30130782810922, 1.07168730604255, 
0.547660829841292, -1.27384604813339, -0.818469328639722, -0.818469328639722, 
-0.36309260914605, 0.0922841103476227, -0.36309260914605, 0.0922841103476227, 
1.00303754933496, -0.36309260914605, -0.36309260914605, 0.547660829841292, 
0.0922841103476227, -0.424262616242215, 2.74751552948485, 0.481959711108376, 
-0.93569501880641, -0.93569501880641, -0.93569501880641, 0.867777137604171, 
-0.93569501880641, -0.484826979703764, 0.867777137604171, 0.416909098501525, 
1.31864517670682, 1.31864517670682, -0.484826979703764, 0.416909098501525, 
0.8011463929092, -0.157726637609687, -0.60417440181917, -0.60417440181917, 
0.288721126599793, 1.93147552111818, -0.279091078365665, 0.163022241531104, 
-0.721204398262433, 1.04724888132464, 1.04724888132464, 0.0397406427137366, 
-0.398121587568641, 0.0397406427137366, 0.915465103278489, 0.477602872996112, 
0.414751835156537, -3.55072964560175, -0.514884848977274, -0.948576962780772, 
-1.4357098109866, -1.05904570874959), date = c(2.02062757853472, 
-0.64625979094064, -0.960011246173035, -1.11688697378923, 1.23624894045373, 
2.9618819442319, 0.451870302372743, -0.489384063324442, -0.489384063324442, 
1.70687612330232, 1.55000039568613, -0.803135518556837, 2.64813048899951, 
2.49125476138331, -0.64625979094064, -0.803135518556837, -1.11688697378923, 
-0.489384063324442, 1.07937321283753, -1.74438988425402, -0.489384063324442, 
1.07937321283753, -0.175632608092047, -0.803135518556837, -0.175632608092047, 
0.138118847140348, 0.451870302372743, 1.07937321283753, 0.922497485221335, 
1.70687612330232, -0.803135518556837, 0.451870302372743, -1.27376270140543, 
-0.0187568804758498, -0.960011246173035, 0.294994574756545, -0.64625979094064, 
0.294994574756545, 0.138118847140348, -0.0187568804758498, -1.27376270140543, 
-1.43063842902163, 1.07937321283753, 0.922497485221335, -0.803135518556837, 
-0.0187568804758498, 1.39312466806993, -0.803135518556837, -0.0187568804758498, 
-0.960011246173035, -0.175632608092047, -0.960011246173035, -0.803135518556837, 
-0.175632608092047, -0.489384063324442, -0.803135518556837, 1.23624894045373, 
1.55000039568613, 0.138118847140348, -0.64625979094064, -0.489384063324442, 
-1.43063842902163, -0.489384063324442, 0.451870302372743, -0.960011246173035, 
0.138118847140348, 0.451870302372743, -0.175632608092047, -0.489384063324442, 
-0.0187568804758498, -0.64625979094064, -1.43063842902163, -0.64625979094064, 
-0.489384063324442, -0.489384063324442, 0.765621757605138, -0.175632608092047, 
-0.489384063324442, -0.489384063324442, -1.27376270140543, -0.960011246173035, 
-0.175632608092047, 0.60874602998894, 2.33437903376711, 1.23624894045373, 
0.451870302372743, -0.332508335708245, 0.294994574756545, -0.489384063324442, 
0.138118847140348, -0.175632608092047, 0.451870302372743), V1 = c(0.719739025958341, 
1.12415930121716, -0.991898300642103, 0.372509496695722, -0.825091958153198, 
0.0988109265710679, -0.638541191451319, -0.501691906388993, -0.270205553547246, 
0.258128004703329, 0.109704401998915, -2.10507532092521, 0.416083398407109, 
-0.629690242666194, -0.521436330601965, -0.287907451117497, 0.588336478609938, 
0.779653140811499, 1.34134796755986, 1.06152181750704, -0.204163858765924, 
-1.60125208238729, 0.464423195618179, 0.00213133214892654, 0.327573910555853, 
-1.29146887490789, 0.887226210661488, -0.469011480105452, 0.87497105080516, 
0.737440923528593, 0.565868685540004, -1.3016815081215, -1.96550266700592, 
0.207064838635297, 1.03292644450894, 0.536592470327665, -0.220504071907694, 
-0.59156307866873, -0.315141139687114, -2.17452122677773, 0.207745680849537, 
-0.326715457329202, 0.565868685540004, 1.39104944919941, -1.24517160433954, 
0.663229122176386, -0.625605189380751, 1.1602439385719, -1.14440695663196, 
-0.659647300092773, 0.312595381842563, 0.815737778166242, 0.48008256654571, 
-0.193951225552317, -0.277694817903891, 0.215234945206182, 0.0695347113587294, 
-0.400246416467168, 0.484167619831152, -0.729093205945296, 0.983905805083629, 
-2.31817893398246, 1.92210637630694, 0.134214721711571, 0.51276299282925, 
-2.69128046738622, 0.595825742966583, 0.373190338909962, -0.0462084650621441, 
0.127406299569166, -0.45062874032096, 0.578123845396332, 1.15479720085798, 
0.168937674637832, 1.24739174199468, 1.15479720085798, 2.23188958378634, 
-1.21317202027024, 0.706803023887773, -2.01248077978851, 0.142384828282456, 
0.578804687610572, 0.0150673342194951, -1.05453578435222, -0.744752576872827, 
-0.153781534912132, -2.68719541410078, 0.832077991308013, 0.934885165658318, 
1.62389748646963, 0.217277471848903, 0.772844718669095), V2 = c(0.0895973007158544, 
0.679390636853413, 0.179245887808762, 0.514248502734896, -0.641746436094719, 
-0.212376887386576, 0.235866048077968, -0.599281315892815, 0.273612821590771, 
-0.740831716565829, -0.811606916902335, -1.58541577391481, 0.990801518334044, 
0.66051725009701, 0.490656769289393, -0.0896998734699646, -0.773860143389532, 
0.844532770971929, 1.13235191900706, 0.5472769295586, -0.386955714883294, 
0.448191649087489, 0.509530156045795, 2.50539080553529, 0.570868663004102, 
-0.863508730482442, 2.83095672708323, -0.528506115556308, 1.11819687893976, 
-0.268997047655782, -0.358645634748692, -0.226531927453878, -1.32118835932519, 
-0.467167608598003, 0.434036609020187, 0.622770476584207, 2.03827448331435, 
0.15093580767416, 0.325514635170878, -2.39225305775099, -0.707803289742126, 
0.235866048077968, -0.764423450011332, 1.00967490509045, -0.962594010953551, 
-0.64646478278382, -0.986185744399053, 0.467065035843891, 0.877561197795632, 
-0.382237368194193, -1.15604622520667, -0.754986756633131, -0.174630113873773, 
0.986083171644943, 0.146217460985059, 0.693545676920713, 0.301922901725375, 
0.103752340783155, -0.0896998734699646, 1.40601602697489, 0.0235404470684476, 
-2.16105406998507, 1.97221762966694, 1.14178861238526, -0.731395023187628, 
-2.34978793754909, -0.122728300293668, -0.54737950231271, -0.740831716565829, 
0.363261408683681, -0.15103838042827, -1.00977747784456, 1.48622792068959, 
0.268894474901672, 0.655798903407911, 0.920026317997536, 1.36826925346208, 
-0.250123660899381, 0.382134795440082, -1.94872846897555, -1.00034078446636, 
-0.396392408261495, 0.160372501052361, 0.169809194430562, -1.28344158581238, 
-2.18936415011967, -1.4249919864854, 0.349106368616379, 1.14178861238526, 
0.858687811039231, 0.103752340783155, -0.585126275825514), V3 = c(0.270351153115729, 
-1.29063289617856, -0.63238661033157, 0.928597438962716, -1.06494845531673, 
0.148105414315573, 0.693509479731649, 0.956807994070443, 0.496035593977553, 
1.27652761862469, 0.449018002131339, -0.472526798054444, -0.0681755081770093, 
-0.688807720547027, -0.322070504146561, -0.707614757285512, 1.31414169210167, 
1.0132291042859, 0.646491887885435, -0.707614757285512, -0.585369018485356, 
0.326772263331183, -0.660597165439297, 0.59007077766998, 0.402000410285125, 
-1.14958012063992, 2.85631870465747, -0.237438838823377, -1.25301882270159, 
-0.359684577623531, -0.0869825449154942, 0.834562255270289, -1.45049270845568, 
-0.491333834792929, 0.0822807857308738, -0.801649940977938, -0.735825312393239, 
-0.641790128700813, 0.101087822469359, -1.09315901042446, 0.749930589947105, 
0.0634737489923889, -2.40965158211844, -0.42550920620823, 4.65239071318282, 
0.872176328747259, -0.500737353162172, -0.152807173500193, 0.402000410285125, 
-0.369088095992775, -0.63238661033157, -0.209228283715648, -0.63238661033157, 
2.5554061168417, 0.467825038869824, 1.48340502274803, -0.350281059254289, 
0.279754671484971, -0.218631802084892, 0.354982818438913, -0.171614210238678, 
-0.453719761315959, -0.265649393931105, -0.162210691869436, 0.336175781700426, 
-1.22480826759386, 0.778141145054833, -1.61035252073281, 0.0634737489923889, 
0.561860222562251, -0.660597165439297, -0.585369018485356, 1.22010650840924, 
0.665298924623921, -1.47870326356341, 0.34557930006967, -0.829860496085666, 
-0.228035320454135, 1.49280854111728, -0.293859949038834, -1.00852734510128, 
-0.604176055223843, -0.651193647070055, 0.749930589947105, -1.38466807987098, 
0.815755218531804, -0.67000068380854, 0.38319337354664, 0.157508932684815, 
0.862772810378017, 0.411403928654367, -0.42550920620823), ID = structure(c(833L, 
712L, 830L, 856L, 288L, 864L, 588L, 589L, 350L, 779L, 862L, 433L, 
847L, 858L, 857L, 731L, 706L, 725L, 174L, 530L, 785L, 805L, 747L, 
277L, 772L, 568L, 790L, 776L, 292L, 754L, 762L, 738L, 715L, 159L, 
160L, 831L, 390L, 782L, 561L, 560L, 774L, 716L, 170L, 290L, 806L, 
581L, 589L, 260L, 334L, 813L, 840L, 443L, 765L, 590L, 264L, 855L, 
783L, 802L, 760L, 443L, 297L, 704L, 261L, 573L, 741L, 446L, 305L, 
173L, 264L, 295L, 276L, 726L, 332L, 775L, 577L, 527L, 274L, 275L, 
742L, 721L, 814L, 342L, 576L, 860L, 854L, 751L, 165L, 393L, 577L, 
344L, 339L, 841L), .Label = c("2311-98425", "2311-98426", "2311-98429", 
"2311-98438", "2311-98468", "2311-98472", "2521-81004", "2521-81005", 
"2521-81006", "2521-81007", "2521-81030", "2521-81031", "2521-81032", 
"2521-81036", "2521-81037", "2521-81056", "2521-81057", "2521-81058", 
"2521-81059", "2521-81060", "2521-81061", "2521-81062", "2521-81063", 
"2521-81064", "2521-81065", "2521-81066", "2521-81067", "2521-81068", 
"2521-81080", "2521-81082", "2521-81083", "2521-81084", "2521-81085", 
"2521-81086", "2521-81087", "2521-81088", "2521-81219", "2521-81220", 
"2521-81221", "2521-81222", "2521-81223", "2521-81224", "2521-81225", 
"2521-81226", "2521-81227", "2521-81228", "2521-81229", "2521-81230", 
"2521-81231", "2521-81232", "2521-81233", "2521-81234", "2521-81235", 
"2521-81236", "2521-81237", "2521-81238", "2521-81239", "2521-81240", 
"2521-81263", "2521-81264", "2521-81265", "2521-81266", "2521-81267", 
"2521-81268", "2521-81269", "2521-81278", "2521-81279", "2521-81280", 
"2521-81281", "2521-81282", "2521-81283", "2521-81284", "2521-81285", 
"2521-81429", "2521-81430", "2521-81431", "2521-81583", "2521-81746", 
"2521-81747", "2521-81748", "2521-81749", "2521-81750", "2521-81754", 
"2521-81755", "2521-81756", "2521-81757", "2521-81758", "2521-81759", 
"2521-81760", "2521-81761", "2521-81762", "2521-81763", "2521-81764", 
"2521-81765", "2521-81766", "2521-81767", "2521-81768", "2521-81777", 
"2521-81778", "2521-81779", "2521-81780", "2521-81781", "2521-81782", 
"2521-81783", "2521-81785", "2521-81786", "2521-81787", "2521-81788", 
"2521-81789", "2521-81790", "2521-81791", "2521-81792", "2521-81793", 
"2521-81803", "2521-81899", "2521-81900", "2560-01376", "2560-01379", 
"2560-01391", "2560-01393", "2560-01395", "2560-01396", "2560-01397", 
"2560-01408", "2560-01419", "2560-01420", "2560-01423", "2560-01425", 
"2560-01436", "2560-01437", "2560-01438", "2560-01447", "2560-01464", 
"2560-01507", "2560-01542", "2560-01543", "2560-01544", "2560-01545", 
"2560-01550", "2560-01551", "2560-01552", "2560-01553", "2560-01554", 
"2560-01556", "2560-01557", "2560-01580", "2560-01581", "2560-01582", 
"2560-01583", "2560-01585", "2560-01597", "2560-01600", "2560-01605", 
"2560-01606", "2560-01632", "2560-01635", "2560-01636", "2560-01640", 
"2560-01641", "2560-01643", "2560-01645", "2560-01655", "2560-01656", 
"2560-01663", "2560-01666", "2560-01667", "2560-01674", "2560-01703", 
"2560-01704", "2560-01712", "2560-01713", "2560-01720", "2560-01732", 
"2560-01739", "2560-01741", "2560-01746", "2560-01749", "2560-01757", 
"2621-73001", "2621-73002", "2621-73003", "2621-73004", "2621-73048", 
"2621-73049", "2621-73050", "2621-73051", "2621-73052", "2621-73053", 
"2621-73054", "2621-73055", "2621-73056", "2621-73057", "2621-73058", 
"2621-73059", "2621-73060", "2621-73061", "2621-73062", "2621-73076", 
"2621-73098", "2621-73099", "2621-73100", "2621-73101", "2621-73102", 
"2621-73103", "2621-73104", "2621-73105", "2621-73142", "2621-73172", 
"2621-73217", "2621-73346", "2621-73347", "2621-73348", "2621-73350", 
"2621-73351", "2621-73352", "2621-73353", "2621-73354", "2621-73355", 
"2621-73356", "2621-73357", "2621-73358", "2621-73359", "2621-73360", 
"2621-73361", "2621-73362", "2621-73363", "2621-73364", "2621-73365", 
"2621-73389", "2621-73390", "2621-73391", "2621-73392", "2621-73393", 
"2621-73394", "2621-73747", "2720-00621", "2730-54001", "2730-54002", 
"2730-54003", "2730-54004", "2730-54005", "2730-54006", "2730-54007", 
"2730-54019", "2730-54020", "2730-54021", "2730-54027", "2730-54028", 
"2730-54029", "2730-54030", "2730-54031", "2730-54060", "2730-54061", 
"2730-54062", "2730-54063", "2730-54064", "2730-54065", "2730-54066", 
"2730-54067", "2730-54068", "2730-54069", "2730-54070", "2730-54071", 
"2730-54073", "2730-54074", "2730-54075", "2730-54076", "2730-54077", 
"2730-54078", "2730-54079", "2730-54080", "2730-54082", "2730-54093", 
"2730-54094", "2730-54095", "2730-54096", "2730-54097", "2730-54098", 
"2730-54099", "2730-54149", "2730-54150", "2730-54151", "2730-54152", 
"2730-54153", "2730-54154", "2730-54155", "2730-54156", "2730-54157", 
"2730-54158", "2730-54159", "2730-54160", "2730-54161", "2730-54162", 
"2730-54163", "2730-54164", "2730-54165", "2730-54166", "2730-54171", 
"2730-54172", "2730-54173", "2730-54174", "2730-54175", "2730-54176", 
"2730-54177", "2730-54178", "2730-54179", "2730-54180", "2730-54181", 
"2730-54182", "2730-54183", "2730-54184", "2730-54185", "2730-54186", 
"2730-54187", "2730-54188", "2730-54189", "2730-54190", "2730-54191", 
"2730-54192", "2730-54193", "2730-54194", "2730-54195", "2730-54196", 
"2730-54197", "2730-54198", "2730-54199", "2730-54200", "2730-54214", 
"2730-54215", "2730-54224", "2730-54225", "2730-54226", "2730-54227", 
"2730-54228", "2730-54229", "2730-54230", "2730-54231", "2730-54232", 
"2730-54233", "2730-54234", "2730-54235", "2730-54236", "2730-54237", 
"2730-54238", "2730-54239", "2730-54259", "2730-54260", "2730-54266", 
"2730-54267", "2730-54278", "2730-54279", "2730-54280", "2730-54281", 
"2730-54282", "2730-54283", "2730-54284", "2730-54285", "2730-54286", 
"2730-54287", "2730-54288", "2730-54289", "2730-54290", "2730-54291", 
"2730-54292", "2730-54293", "2730-54294", "2730-54295", "2730-54296", 
"2730-54297", "2730-54298", "2730-54299", "2730-54300", "2730-54301", 
"2730-54302", "2730-54303", "2730-54304", "2730-54305", "2730-54306", 
"2730-54307", "2730-54308", "2730-54309", "2730-54310", "2730-54311", 
"2730-54312", "2730-54313", "2730-54314", "2730-54315", "2730-54316", 
"2730-54317", "2730-54318", "2730-54319", "2730-54320", "2730-54321", 
"2730-54325", "2730-54326", "2730-54327", "2730-54328", "2730-54329", 
"2730-54330", "2730-54331", "2730-54332", "2730-54333", "2730-54334", 
"2730-54335", "2730-54336", "2730-54337", "2730-54338", "2730-54339", 
"2730-54340", "2730-54341", "2730-54342", "2730-54343", "2730-54344", 
"2730-54345", "2730-54347", "2730-54349", "2730-54350", "2730-54351", 
"2730-54352", "2730-54353", "2730-54354", "2730-54355", "2730-54356", 
"2730-54357", "2730-54358", "2730-54359", "2730-54360", "2730-54361", 
"2730-54362", "2730-54363", "2730-54364", "2730-54365", "2730-54367", 
"2730-54368", "2730-54369", "2730-54377", "2730-54379", "2730-54383", 
"2730-54384", "2730-54385", "2730-54386", "2730-54387", "2730-54388", 
"2730-54391", "2730-54392", "2730-54394", "2730-54395", "2730-54396", 
"2730-54397", "2730-54398", "2730-54399", "2730-54400", "2730-54406", 
"2730-54407", "2730-54408", "2730-54409", "2730-54410", "2730-54411", 
"2730-54416", "2730-54417", "2730-54418", "2730-54428", "2730-54429", 
"2730-54430", "2730-54443", "2730-54487", "2730-54489", "2730-54501", 
"2730-54502", "2730-54503", "2730-54504", "2730-54505", "2730-54506", 
"2730-54507", "2730-54508", "2730-54509", "2730-54510", "2730-54511", 
"2730-54512", "2730-54513", "2730-54514", "2730-54515", "2730-54516", 
"2730-54517", "2730-54518", "2730-54519", "2730-54520", "2730-54531", 
"2730-54532", "2730-54533", "2730-54534", "2730-54535", "2730-54543", 
"2730-54544", "2730-54550", "2730-54551", "2730-54552", "2730-54553", 
"2730-54554", "2730-54555", "2730-54556", "2730-54557", "2730-54558", 
"2730-54559", "2730-54560", "2730-54561", "2730-54562", "2730-54563", 
"2730-54564", "2730-54565", "2730-54566", "2730-54567", "2730-54570", 
"2730-54571", "2730-54572", "2730-54573", "2730-54574", "2730-54575", 
"2730-54576", "2730-54582", "2730-54598", "2730-54599", "2730-54655", 
"2730-54656", "2730-54657", "2730-54658", "2730-54659", "2730-54660", 
"2730-54661", "2730-54662", "2730-54663", "2730-54664", "2730-54665", 
"2730-54666", "2730-54667", "2730-54668", "2730-54669", "2730-54675", 
"2730-54676", "2730-54677", "2730-54680", "2730-54681", "2730-54685", 
"2730-54687", "2730-54688", "2730-54691", "2730-54694", "2730-54695", 
"2730-54696", "2730-54697", "2730-54698", "2730-54699", "2730-54700", 
"2730-54704", "2730-54705", "2730-54706", "2730-54707", "2730-54708", 
"2730-54709", "2730-54710", "2730-54711", "2730-54712", "2730-54713", 
"2730-54714", "2730-54715", "2730-54716", "2730-54718", "2730-54719", 
"2730-54720", "2730-54721", "2730-54722", "2730-54723", "2730-54724", 
"2730-54725", "2730-54726", "2730-54727", "2730-54728", "2730-54729", 
"2730-54730", "2730-54731", "2730-54738", "2730-54739", "2730-54740", 
"2730-54741", "2730-54742", "2730-54743", "2730-54744", "2730-54745", 
"2730-54746", "2730-54747", "2730-54749", "2730-54750", "2730-54752", 
"2730-54754", "2730-54755", "2730-54763", "2730-54764", "2730-54769", 
"2730-54770", "2730-54771", "2730-54772", "2730-54773", "2730-54774", 
"2730-54775", "2730-54776", "2730-54777", "2730-54778", "2730-54779", 
"2730-54780", "2730-54781", "2730-54782", "2730-54783", "2730-54784", 
"2730-54785", "2730-54786", "2730-54787", "2730-54788", "2730-54789", 
"2730-54790", "2730-54791", "2730-54792", "2730-54793", "2730-54794", 
"2730-54795", "2730-54796", "2730-54799", "2730-54800", "2730-54819", 
"2730-54820", "2730-54821", "2730-54823", "2730-54824", "2730-54825", 
"2730-54826", "2730-54827", "2730-54828", "2730-54829", "2730-54830", 
"2730-54831", "2730-54832", "2730-54833", "2730-54834", "2730-54835", 
"2730-54836", "2730-54837", "2730-54838", "2730-54839", "2730-54840", 
"2730-54841", "2730-54842", "2730-54843", "2730-54844", "2730-54845", 
"2730-54846", "2730-54847", "2730-54848", "2730-54849", "2730-54850", 
"2730-54851", "2730-54852", "2730-54853", "2730-54854", "2730-54855", 
"2730-54856", "2730-54908", "2730-54909", "2730-54911", "2730-54912", 
"2730-54914", "2730-54915", "2730-54929", "2780-51001", "2780-51002", 
"2780-51003", "2780-51004", "2780-51005", "2780-51006", "2780-51007", 
"2780-51008", "2780-51009", "2780-51010", "2780-51011", "2780-51012", 
"2780-51013", "2780-51014", "2780-51015", "2780-51016", "2780-51017", 
"2780-51018", "2780-51019", "2780-51020", "2780-51021", "2780-51022", 
"2780-51023", "2780-51024", "2780-51025", "2780-51026", "2780-51027", 
"2780-51028", "2780-51029", "2780-51030", "2780-51031", "2780-51032", 
"2780-51033", "2780-51034", "2780-51035", "2780-51036", "2780-51037", 
"2780-51038", "2780-51039", "2780-51040", "2780-51041", "2780-51042", 
"2780-51043", "2780-51044", "2780-51045", "2780-51046", "2780-51048", 
"2780-51049", "2780-51050", "2780-51051", "2780-51052", "2780-51053", 
"2780-51054", "2780-51055", "2780-51056", "2780-51057", "2780-51058", 
"2780-51059", "2780-51067", "2780-51068", "2780-51069", "2780-51070", 
"2780-51071", "2780-51072", "2780-51073", "2780-51074", "2780-51075", 
"2780-51076", "2780-51077", "2780-51078", "2780-51079", "2780-51080", 
"2780-51081", "2780-51082", "2780-51083", "2780-51084", "2780-51085", 
"2780-51086", "2780-51087", "2780-51088", "2780-51089", "2780-51090", 
"2780-51091", "2780-51092", "2780-51093", "2780-51094", "2780-51095", 
"2780-51096", "2780-51097", "2780-51098", "2780-51099", "2780-51100", 
"2780-51101", "2780-51102", "2780-51103", "2780-51104", "2780-51105", 
"2780-51106", "2780-51107", "2780-51108", "2780-51109", "2780-51110", 
"2780-51111", "2780-51112", "2780-51113", "2780-51114", "2780-51115", 
"2780-51116", "2780-51117", "2780-51118", "2780-51119", "2780-51120", 
"2780-51121", "2780-51122", "2780-51123", "2780-51124", "2780-51125", 
"2780-51126", "2780-51127", "2780-51128", "2780-51129", "2780-51130", 
"2780-51131", "2780-51132", "2780-51133", "2780-51134", "2780-51135", 
"2780-51136", "2780-51137", "2780-51138", "2780-51139", "2780-51140", 
"2780-51141", "2780-51142", "2780-51143", "2780-51144", "2780-51145", 
"2780-51146", "2780-51147", "2780-51153", "2780-51154", "2780-51155", 
"2780-51156", "2780-51157", "2780-51158", "2780-51159", "2780-51160", 
"2780-51161", "2780-51162", "2780-51163", "2780-51164", "2780-51165", 
"2780-51166", "2780-51167", "2780-51168", "2780-51169", "2780-51170", 
"2780-51171", "2780-51177", "2780-51178", "2780-51179", "2780-51180", 
"2780-51181", "2780-51182", "2780-51183", "2780-51184", "2780-51185", 
"2780-51186", "2780-51187", "2780-51188", "2780-51189", "2780-51190", 
"2780-51191", "2780-51192", "2780-51193", "2780-51194", "2780-51195", 
"2780-51196", "2780-51197", "2780-51198", "2780-51199", "2780-51200", 
"2780-51201", "2780-51202", "2780-51203", "2780-51204", "2780-51205", 
"2780-51206", "2780-51207", "2780-51208", "2780-51209", "2780-51210", 
"2780-51211", "2780-51212", "2780-51213", "2780-51214", "2780-51215", 
"2780-51216", "2780-51217", "2780-51218", "2780-51219", "2780-51220", 
"2780-51221", "2780-51222", "2780-51223", "2780-51224", "2780-51225", 
"2780-51226", "2780-51227", "2780-51228", "2780-51229", "2780-51230", 
"2780-51231", "2780-51232", "2780-51233", "2780-51234", "2780-51235", 
"2780-51236", "2780-51237", "2780-51239", "2780-51261", "2780-51265", 
"2780-51266", "unk1"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(6L, 
8L, 17L, 20L, 25L, 28L, 34L, 35L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 41L, 50L, 55L, 
59L, 62L, 64L, 65L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 82L, 84L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 
96L, 99L, 107L, 110L, 112L, 117L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 123L, 124L, 
135L, 141L, 144L, 145L, 151L, 152L, 161L, 164L, 168L, 170L, 171L, 
173L, 176L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 186L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 203L, 204L, 
215L, 216L, 217L, 225L, 227L, 229L, 231L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 241L, 
251L, 260L, 272L, 274L, 283L, 290L, 292L, 294L, 296L, 297L, 306L, 
307L, 308L, 309L, 314L, 320L, 323L, 325L, 327L, 328L, 331L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the specific dataset you shared it seems that you have a single measurement per ID (except for one in which you have two measurements). Because the residuals are also based on the estimated random effects, you see this behavior.

Comment: (+1) Good catch, Dimitris. I was thinking about maybe an omitted variable....

Comment: Thanks Dimitris.  I didn't realize that about that specific dataset.  I'll select one of the two observations for the duplicated individual in my final model.

Comment: However, this leads to another question.  I'm running similar models for several species and for some of the other species I have two or three observations for some individuals, however, I still see similar linear trends in these models. @RobertLong, you mentioned this could also be due to a missing variable.  Is there are a good approach to determine what could be missing?  My sample size is small, so I'm worried about including too many explanatory variables in my models.

Comment: @tnt I would google "omitted variable bias" and see what you can learn about that first. If you still have a issue, then please post a new question.